# select data from mysql using two column ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, str-to-date

I have data like this

```
sno name    date        time

1   Irona   2016-01-01  10:00:00
2   Meona   2016-01-02  21:00:00
3   Lessa   2016-01-02  8:00:00
4   Airik   2016-01-03  10:00:00
```

I m trying query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `appointment` where (date <= '2016-01-02' and time >= '21:00:00') and (date >= '2016-01-03' and time >= '10:00:00')
```

I want those appointment which are between 2016-01-02 and 2016-01-03 and also between 9 pm to 10 am

Comment: What the error you  got? and what are the types of date and date columns?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `appointment` A
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(A.date, ' ', A.time), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '2016-01-02 21:00:00' AND '2016-01-03 10:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Query `date <= '2016-01-02'` `and` `date >= '2016-01-03'` returns nothing. 
you should change it to `date >= '2016-01-02' and date <= '2016-01-03'`

```
SELECT * FROM `appointment` 
where date >= '2016-01-02' and date <= '2016-01-03' 
and time <= '21:00:00' and time >= '10:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do it like this:

```
...
WHERE
to_char(date, '%Y%m%d') between '20160102' and '20160103'
AND to_char(timedate, '%H') between '10' and '21'
```